# Can I use "Making acquaintance" for a friend I meet later?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I saw a friend at a party but couldn't tak to her. Later I meet her again, can I say that we couldn't make acquaintance at the party?

If not then what can be said?

Comment: “*Sorry I didn’t get a chance to talk to you at the party.”* You only make acquaintance with someone when you first meet them. If they are already a friend you can’t make their acquaintance again except if you haven’t spoken with them for years and you’ve grown apart you might get reacquainted with them.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb *actually* will express what you want, if you only saw her at the party and did not talk to her or otherwise meet her.

> I saw a friend at a party but couldn't talk to her. Later I actually made her acquaintance.

Comment: I think if you call them a friend then you’ve already made their acquaintance.  See my comment above.